# Simple Neural Network with MNIST stuck at 17% missclasification error

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist

Hello Im putting my code for inspection because Ive been playing with my neural network implementation in python for a few weeks and I cant seem to reach a misclasification error below 17% some times 16%. ve been trying different learning rate values, different hidden neurons number and still not a lot of mprovement. Im well aware my implementation is the basic traditional neural network, but I was expecting better results according to other implementations ive seen in internet. I hope this is of interest for you guys, it would be really cool if you could point me new ideas about what could be the problem in my code, or maybe you think this is the best I can do with a traditional implementation and I should add something new, that would be cool too.

In any case, here is my code, I hope is readable enough, I tried to do it as simple as possible, since its my way to understand how neural networks work.

Edit:Perhaps my question is not so clear, basically I would like, if its of interest for you guys, is to help me find details in my current implementation that could improve my misclasification error below 17% because apparently its the best my implementation can do. I would be very thankful for any advise or idea, Im deeply interested in this topic, but Im a beginner and it would be great to have some smart ideas that can help me improve my implementation.

File: mnist_dataset.py - Extract the mnist data

```
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack

train_input_file = open("dataset/train-images-idx3-ubyte", "rb")
train_output_file = open("/dataset/train-labels-idx1-ubyte", "rb")
test_input_file = open("dataset/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte", "rb")
test_output_file = open("dataset/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte", "rb")


def readData(f,labels = False,scale = 1):
    header = hex(unpack('>L',np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32,count=1)[0])[0])
num = int(unpack('>L',np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32,count=1)[0])[0])
col = 1
row = 1

if labels == False:
    row = int(unpack('>L',np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32,count=1)[0])[0])
    col = int(unpack('>L',np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32,count=1)[0])[0])

    data = np.zeros((int(num/scale),col*row))
    for i in range(0,int(num/scale),1):
    data[i] = np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.ubyte,count=col*row)
return data


def getMNISTData():
    def norm(v):
        return v/255

train_input = readData(train_input_file, scale=1)/255.0
train_out = readData(train_output_file, True,scale=1)
test_input = readData(test_input_file)/255.0
test_out = readData(test_output_file, True)

print "Train input: " + str(train_input.shape)
print "Train output: " + str(train_out.shape)
print "Test input: " + str(test_input.shape)
print "Test output: " + str(test_out.shape)

train_input_file.close()
train_output_file.close()
test_input_file.close()
test_output_file.close()
return (train_input,train_out,test_input,test_out)
```

File: NN.py - neural network implementation

```
import mnist_dataset
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def encode_data_10(v):
    e = (0.0) * np.ones((1, 10), dtype=float)
    e[:, int(v)] = 1.0
    return e.tolist()

def encode_data_1(v):
    n = -1.0 + ((0.2)*v)
    return n

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test =  mnist_dataset.getMNISTData()

learning_rate = 1.0
iter = 3000
sample_size = 30
num_hidden_neurons = 500
num_output_neurons = 10

if num_output_neurons > 1:
    y_train = np.matrix(np.array(map(encode_data_10,y_train)))
    y_test = np.matrix(np.array(map(encode_data_10,y_test)))
else:
    y_train = np.matrix(map(encode_data_1,y_train))
    y_test = np.matrix(map(encode_data_1,y_test))


def getSample(sample_size,x,y):
    r = random.sample(xrange(1, len(y), 1), sample_size)
    x_r = np.zeros((sample_size,x.shape[1]))
    y_r = np.zeros((sample_size,y.shape[1]))
    for i,n in enumerate(r):
        x_r[i] = x[n]
        y_r[i] = y[n]
    return (x_r,y_r)

inputVector, targetVector = getSample(sample_size, x_train, y_train)




hiddenWeights = np.mat(np.random.random((num_hidden_neurons, x_train.shape[1])))
print "W0 shape: " + str(hiddenWeights.shape)
outputWeights = np.mat(np.random.random((num_output_neurons,num_hidden_neurons)))
print "W1 shape: " + str(outputWeights.shape)


def act_func_l1(a):
    return (1.0/(1 + np.exp(-a)))

def der_act_func_l1(a):
    return act_func_l1(a)*(1.0 - act_func_l1(a))


def feedforward(l0):
    global hiddenWeights
    global outputWeights

    Z1 = l0 * hiddenWeights.T

    layer1 = np.matrix(act_func_l1(np.asarray(Z1)))

    Z2 = layer1 * outputWeights.T

    layer2 = act_func_l1(np.asarray(Z2))

    return (layer1,layer2)

def miss(x,y):
    layer1, layer2 = feedforward(x)

    def c(n):
        if n > 0.5:
            return 1.0
        else:
            return 0.0

    layer2 = map(lambda v: map(c, v), layer2)

    def cc(t):
        return np.abs(cmp(np.array(y[t[0]]).tolist()[0], np.array(t[1]).tolist()))
    return (np.sum(map(cc, enumerate(layer2))))

miss_x = np.zeros((iter, 1))
for j in xrange(iter):

    hiddenActualInput = inputVector * hiddenWeights.T

    hiddenOutputVector = np.matrix(act_func_l1(np.asarray(hiddenActualInput)))

    outputActualInput = hiddenOutputVector * outputWeights.T

    outputVector = act_func_l1(np.asarray(outputActualInput))


    layer2_error2 = np.square(outputVector - targetVector)
    print "Error: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(layer2_error2)))


    m = miss(x_test,y_test)
    miss_x[j] = m
    print str(j) + " - Misses (%): " + str(m)
    if m <= 2000:
        learning_rate = 0.05


    outputDelta = np.mat(der_act_func_l1(np.asarray(outputVector))*np.asarray(outputVector - targetVector))
    hiddenDelta =  np.mat(der_act_func_l1(np.asarray(hiddenOutputVector)) * np.asarray((outputDelta*outputWeights)))

    hiddenWeights = np.mat(hiddenWeights.T - (learning_rate*np.asarray(inputVector.T*hiddenDelta))).T
    outputWeights = np.mat(outputWeights.T - (learning_rate*np.asarray(hiddenOutputVector.T*outputDelta))).T

    inputVector, targetVector = getSample(sample_size, x_train, y_train)

plt.plot(xrange(iter), miss_x, label = 'Miss rate(%)')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you asking here because you think that you have a bug in your code or to seek advice with machine learning? If it is the latter you should consider asking at [Cross Validated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) which is a site specifically about statistics, machine learning and such, but in that case you should include more statistical information (what are you trying to learn exactly? How much data you have? etc.)

Comment: Thanks, esentially Im looking for any advise that could help me improve my current implementation, either because of a bug or simply its the best my neural network can do. Basically what Im trying to learn is if there is any way I can tweak my neural network to improve my misclasification error or I need a more advanced implementation.

Comment: Have you used numerical approximation to confirm that your gradient is correct?

Comment: @Outlaw Lemur: Sorry for the dumb question, but how do I do that? Like doing the derivatives on paper first? Does that mean I should try my neural network with fixed initial weights instead of random values?

Comment: @MeMoVsGodzilla I'd see [this page](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Gradient_checking_and_advanced_optimization) for more details, but approximate the derivative of each weight wrt to the loss function and compare that to the gradient you computed in your code

Comment: @Outlaw Lemur Thanks this seems helpful.